# How to increase block.number in a truffle solidity test?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, truffle-test

Is there any way to increase the `block.number` (e.g. mine a block) in a solidity based truffle test?

I am able to do this just fine with a javascript based test by making an RPC call to the evm, but I can't find any information on whether we can do this with a test written in solidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like it is possible to easily increase the block number using truffle/ganache with a solidity test.

For a javascript based test, you can always advance the block number one by one using:

```js
advanceBlock = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.send({
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      method: 'evm_mine',
      id: new Date().getTime()
    }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) { return reject(err) }
      const newBlockHash = web3.eth.getBlock('latest').hash

      return resolve(newBlockHash)
    })
  })
```

This doesn't scale well if you need to mine a large number of blocks however. Ganache does not support mining multiple blocks at once.

The workaround I discovered (as I'm sure others have too) is to replace calls to `block.number` in your contract to a virtual function:

```
function _blockNumber() internal virtual view returns (uint256) {
    return block.number;
}
```

Then for testing purposes, you can test against a test contract that inherits from your original contract, with the `_blockNumber()` function overridden:

```
contract TestableMyContract is MyContract {
    uint256 _fakeBlockNumber;
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) MyContract(name_, symbol_) {
    }

    function __test_setBlockNumber(uint256 blockNumber_) public {
        _fakeBlockNumber = blockNumber_;
    }

    function _blockNumber() internal override view returns (uint256) {
        if (0 == _fakeBlockNumber) {
            return super._blockNumber();
        }
        return _fakeBlockNumber;
    }
}
```

In your javascript based test, you can simply change the block number:

```
contract("MyContract", (accounts) => {
    it("should do something when the block number increases", async () => {
        const instance = await TestMyContract.deployed();
        const deployBlock = await web3.eth.getBlock("latest");
        const deployBlockNumber = deployBlock.number;
        await instance.__test_setBlockNumber(deployBlockNumber + BLOCKS_TO_INCREASE);
    });
});
```

Because we are simply calling a contract function to "change" (the contract's view of) the block number, we can similarly call it from a solidity test:

```
import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/TestableMyContract.sol";

contract TestMyContract {
    function test_increase_block_number() public {
        TestableMyContract c = TestableMyContract(DeployedAddresses.TestableMyContract());
        c.__test_setBlockNumber(DESIRED_BLOCK_NUMBER);
    }
}
```